# SaveChangesAsync() + lock

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, lock

Помогите с идеей решения проблемы, дано:

1. EF Core Code first
2. MS Sql Server
3. ASP.Net server с асинхронными запросами.

У меня есть база с данными пользователей, мне нужно поменять сразу несколько таблиц в базе для выбранного пользователя, причем данные гарантированно должны быть либо обновлены, либо не тронуты. В момент изменения данных, они могут быть запрошены пользователем в ином потоке (запросы асинхронные).

Проблема в следубющем :
Сейчас когда изменяются данные, для каждого конкретного пользователя используется `lock(sync)` - как способ синхронизации от двух паралельных запросов, к примеру первый запрос пишет в базу, второй читает.

Когда я обновляю базу, мне нужно обновлять ее под `lock` объектом, соответственно я не могу использовать `SaveChangesAsync()`, так как его нельзя использовать под пконструкцией `lock`. ТАк же я не могу обойтись без локирования, так как обновляю сразу ряд таблиц и по этому, должна быть гарантия, что пользователь не запросит случайно часть новых и часть старых данных. В принципе, все в порядке, однако процесс обновления достаточно долог, и для надежности обернут в транзакцию, из-за чего получается что база недоступна для всех иных пользователей данного сервиса, ведь обновление происходит в синхронном режиме. И если к примеру 1000 пользователей сделают запрос на обновление данных, то получается что сервис может висеть даже до часу обрабатывая эти запросы. Буду благодарен, если подскажете возможное нормальное решение проблемы.

Ниже приведен схематичный код, который иллюстрирует описанное:

```
object sync = new object()
async Task MyMethod(MyDBContext context)
{
    // переключили поток но это не делает погоды так как далее идут синхронные операции и база виснет намертво для всех обращений к ней            
    using transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(); 
    lock(sync)
    {
        UpdateTb1(context);
        UpdateTb2(context);
        UpdateTb3(context);
        transaction.Commit();
    }  
}
        
void UpdateTb1(context)
{
    context.Tb1.Add(VeryLongData);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
void UpdateTb2(context)
{
    context.Tb2.Add(VeryLongData);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
void UpdateTb3(context)
{
    context.Tb3.Add(VeryLongData);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Повторюсь еще раз, это лишь пример кода для иллюстрации проблемы, проблема в подходе к решению, а не в коде, по этому не кидайтесь помидорами за то что приложенный пример не воспроизводим. Буду благодарен за предложенные решения.

Как только произошло первое сохранение данных, транзакция блокирует базу, и ни кто не может к ней достучаться.

В реальном коде, все еще обернуто в `try-catch`, для того что бы если будет ошибка во время операции сохранения данных, она прошла незаметно, а транзакция откатила бы изменения в базе.

Comment: не вдаваясь в детали того, что вы делаете, просто как варианты для вас: 1) оптимизировать долгие запросы (например, bulk операции или испольовать что то более низкоуровневое типа dapper) 2) существуют асинхронные семафоры, так что можно лочить ими асинзронно 3) если проблема в архитектуре, она решается отдельными инстансами БД для чтения и для записи (чтобы читатели не ждали - см также CQRS+event sourcing)

Comment: Отдельные инстансы не помогут, я даже из Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio не могу не чего прочесть когда лочится на запись транзакция

Comment: отдельные инстансы помогут, если у вас кластер и вы пишете только в определенные инстансы, и читаете с остальных. Но это черевато проблемами с консистентностью. Также, в зависимости от вашего случая, рассмотрите возможность кеширования (то есть читать реже из БД) или даже NoSQL бд, которые могут быть быстрее на тех операциях, что вы используете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать асинхронную блокировку вместо `lock`, а также запускать синхронные методы в отдельном потоке.

```csharp
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

async Task MyMethod(MyDBContext context)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        using transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(); 
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            UpdateTb1(context);
            UpdateTb2(context);
            UpdateTb3(context);
            transaction.Commit();
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

В это случае основной поток не будет заблокирован, пока идет ожидание и выполнение транзакции, и другие пользователи смогут пользоваться сервисом.

Как я понимаю, вы не могли использовать асинхронные методы из-за `lock`, теперь вы сможете это исправить и избавиться от `Task.Run()`, который я предложил.

Кстати, обратите внимание, что `SemaphoreSlim` реализует `IDisposable`, для аккуратного его применения позаботьтесь о том, чтобы вызвать ему `Dispose()`, когда он станет не нужен.

Comment: Возможно это то что я искал. Один вопрос, а что если у нас добавится еще один метод который иснхронный по сигнатуре, будет использовать semaphore.Wait() но вызывается из иного потока. Нормально ли все отработает или же будут перебои ?

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar светофор потокобезопасный, можете использовать его в каких угодно потоках, кстати я дополнил ответ.

Comment: @aeport имою ввиду, что если один метод будет WaitAsync(), а иной Wait() использовать, то все все равно будет корректно локироваться верно ?

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar я думаю, да. Попробуйте.

Comment: Да, работает корректно. Благодарюю.